# Confusion about r-value references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo { };

Foo createFoo() { return Foo(); }

void bar(Foo &&) { std::cout << "in bar(Foo &&)\n"; }

void bar(Foo const &) { std::cout << "in bar(Foo const &)\n"; }

void baz(Foo &&f) {
    std::cout << "in baz, ";
    bar(f);
    // bar(std::move(f));
}

int main()
{
    baz(createFoo());
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is: `in baz, in bar(Foo &&)`, but I'm getting: `in baz, in bar(Foo const &)`.  If I switch the calls to `bar` (see the comment) I get the expected output, but this seems wrong to me.  Is there some reason the compiler can't call `bar(Foo &&)` without me converting a `Foo&&` to a `Foo&&`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `f` in `Foo &&f` is an lvalue, since it is named, so it will not bind directly to an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside `baz(Foo&& f)`, `f` is an **lvalue**. Therefore, to pass it on to `bar` as an rvalue reference you have to cast it to an rvalue. You can do this with a `static_cast<Foo&&>(f)`, or with `std::move(f)`.

This is to avoid accidentally moving things multiple times in the same function e.g. with multiple calls to `bar(f)` inside `baz`.

Comment: Please _not_ with `static_cast`!

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Why not `static_cast`?  Obviously `std::move` is cleaner to read and will always work, but is there some other reason `static_cast` would be bad?

Comment: @Stephen Newell `static_cast` doesn't clearly express the intention, potentially misleading your readers into thinking you for example mistyped `&` as `&&`.

Comment: @StephenNewell: There is the content and there is the presentation. In this case both are equivalent from a content point of view, but one is specific (and thus clear) while the other is a generic construct (and thus questions arose as to why it was used, if it was used correctly, if it was really intended, ....)

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams: Strictly, `f` is an rvalue reference, and an lvalue. The result of `static_cast<Foo&&>(f)` is also an rvalue reference, but an xvalue (a type of rvalue). I.e. you're using static_cast to convert from type T to itself, but as a side effect you're changing the l/r-valueness. Otherwise your explanation is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

In short, the rule is that a named rvalue reference is an lvalue. This is to prevent automatically moving out of a named variable that you then need to use later. In contrast unnamed temporaries can never be used again and so can be automatically moved from.

I found this series http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ to be pretty helpful even though it's a little bit old.